# corrupted loose object on git remote repo

Tags: git

I have git repo on an Apache server via web-dav. Recently I realized that I can't commit because `Cannot obtain needed blob` (as git reports). I used `git fsck` on the server (where I have root account) and I learned that:

```
fatal: loose object 169c3a2314c846d858492015a104ff184683b03d (stored in ./objects/16/9c3a2314c846d858492015a104ff184683b03d) is corrupt
```

Surprisingly, I can do `git clone` on the server from one directory to another:

```
git clone /srv/git/repo ./copy
```

and I don't get any error message, but I can't run 'clone' from a local machine via http. The cloned blob `169c3a2314c846d858492015a104ff184683b03d` is identical with the one that is presumably corrupted.

Any ideas for an easy fix?

PS. yes, I've read other posts here, but they mostly relate to a broken local copy. And yes, I made a backup copy of the repo.